# Swift - SceneKit - How to properly orient Camera and Light Node with SCNCylinder (that's a 3D rendering of coordinate path)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, scnnode

I'm trying to recreate a feature like this:
[image]

Where I take coordinates and elevation points of a hiking path and create a SceneKit rendering and animation. The orange ball animates along the white path while the entire object slowly rotates on the X - axis 360 degrees and loops.

I've gotten the path to plot accurately as a SCNCylinder. However I cannot figure out how to correctly orient the camera and lighting to recreate the view as shown in the first image. I've unfortunately sunk way too much time into trying and have gotten no where! I'm quite familiar with Swift overall but no experience whatsoever with SceneKit and am trying to learn. I'm quite confused with properly positioning the camera, light and X number of cylinders that make up the path.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
func sceneKit () {
    
    let sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.canvasView.frame.width, height: self.canvasView.frame.height))
    self.canvasView.addSubview(sceneView)
    
    let scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.scene = scene

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera

    let ambientLight = SCNLight()
    ambientLight.type = SCNLight.LightType.ambient
    ambientLight.color = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
    cameraNode.light = ambientLight

    let light = SCNLight()
    light.type = SCNLight.LightType.spot
    light.spotInnerAngle = 30.0
    light.spotOuterAngle = 80.0
    light.castsShadow = true
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = light

    var pathNodeLst = self.get3DPath(scene: scene)

    var lastPost = SCNVector3()
    
    for pathNode in pathNodeLst {
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(pathNode)
        lastPost = pathNode.position
    }
    
    cameraNode.position = lastPost
    lightNode.position =  lastPost

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
   
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    
}
```

But this not really even close to what I want and have totally hit a dead end in better ideas.

[image]

The blue background is just for testing and the path in the blue image is correct - it's a different hike than the black example.

Basically I don't know how to get the point of view to face above and on an angle like the black image. How to achieve the cascading white shadow below the path is also a complete mystery.

Any help would be desperately appreciated - thanks!

Here's the best I was able to get (by omitting the camera and light nodes completely and then manually moving the camera with iOS touch gestures)